# Orchard getting the field from type ContentItem

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I have a content item called Event, which has a taxonomy field called Section attached via the content definition area.

What is the ***easiest*** way to retrieve the Section field from the content within an alternate? My alternate ***is not*** overriding an Event, so Model.ContentItem is not possible. Within my alternate my Event object instance is of type ContentItem which I am retrieving through the ContentManager.

This is what i'm doing at the moment:

```
ContentItem content = WorkContext.Resolve<IContentManager>().Get(id);
var = content.Parts.ElementAt(13).Fields.ElementAt(0);
```

I realise that in the above code the index's could change, the only other way I can think of doing this is by inserting Lambda expressions in the place of the integers.

content.Parts.ElementAt(13) returns object of type ContentPart 
content.Parts.ElementAt(13).Fields.ElementAt(0) returns object of type TaxonomyField. Whereas I believe I need the TermPart?

If it cannot be achieved in a simple way, why is it so difficult to perform such a simple task?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you do not need the ContentManager on the template.

On the Model you have the ContentItem. You can retrive the field like this:

```
var contentItem = Model.ContentItem;
var terms = contentItem.Event.TaxonomyFieldName.Terms;
```

On terms you have the terms of the ContentItem.

Comment: Hi Martinbc, thanks for your answer. Though I must use the ContentManager as I am retrieving the content which is currently attached to the current url. The alternate's Model.ContentItem is not an Event.

Comment: Then you should write a custom Shape (http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Accessing-and-rendering-shapes) read Creating a Shape Method. Use the ContentManager in that method, not in the view

Comment: More info here http://chrisbower.com/2011/09/12/shape-methods-as-an-alternative-to-widgets/

Comment: I appreciate your answer but  it does not answer my question. I do not wish to write a custom shape. I simply want to know how to access a field using the method in the original question.

Comment: You can use the same, cast the Event content item to dynamic and use content.Event.TaxonomyFieldName.Terms.